# Setting value of HTML element's attribute equal to another attribute's value using Javscript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to Javascript, and am running into a problem:

I am trying to set the width value of a div equal to the width of a span wrapper.
The div in question is nested within the wrapper, if that has any effect on the problem. Here is the code I am using.

```
<script>
function O(i) {
    return typeof i == 'object' ? i : document.getElementById(i)
}

function S(i) {
    return O(i).style
}
</script>

...

<script> S('idOfDiv').width = S('idOfWrapper').width </script>
```

This is not working. If I change the right-hand side of the assignment to, say, "20px", it works.
But as is shown in the example, it has no effect on the width of the div. I have defined the first two functions in the Head tags, and the assignment takes place after both the wrapper and div code.
The console log doesn't throw any errors to help with debugging.
Why is this? Is it something to do with the attribute value not being the correct type?

To clarify, the width of the wrapper is determined primarily by the font-size of buttons within the wrapper (external CSS, not inline), which in turn scale by using viewport units. This was done in an effort to add Responsive Web Design features, which has made quite a mess of things.

I'm thinking of simply adding the width of the buttons altogether, since they seem to be div elements, and using this value for the width instead of the wrapper's width, which may not even be possible.

Comment: FYI, a `span` may not be the parent of a `div` in HTML. If you set the `display` property of the `span` to `block` in CSS, you may have more luck.

Comment: How are you setting the width of the wrapper? The `style` property only returns inline styles, not styles inherited from CSS.

Answer (score 1):

`style` property of elements contains the `inline styles` of elements not their computed styles .
so if you want to get an element's property value , you have to use `window.getComputedStyle()` which accepts an element as parameter and returns it's entire styles , then you can get it's width by `window.getComputedStyle(myElement).width`

see the example below :
HTML

```
  <body>
    <div id="elm1" style="width:200px"></div>
    <div id="elm2"></div>
    <script>
      assignWidth(
        document.getElementById("elm1"),
        document.getElementById("elm2")
      );
    </script>
  </body>
```

CSS

```
        div {
        height: 100px;
        background-color: blue;
        margin: 10px;
    }
```

Javascript

```
 const assignWidth = (elm1,elm2) => {
        elm2.style.width = window.getComputedStyle(elm1).width ;
    }
```

you can inspect your document (press F12) and select div#elm2 to see it's `inline width style`
read more about `getComputedStyle` :
[Window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)
[JavaScript Window getComputedStyle() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getcomputedstyle.asp)

Answer (score 0):

A span is an inline element. It doesn't have width or height, and you can't set its width or height. Your code should work, but only on block elements, like div.

Edit:
You can use `element.offsetWidth` to get the element's actual rendered width.